# Reading boost::asio::streambuf yields bad data

Tags: boost, boost-asio, streambuf

I'm using boost::asio to create a TCP client.  I'm testing it out by loading a web site.  I can create a connection, read, have my callback fired, etc, no problem.  However, at the of every packet, I'm finding this, or something like it:

```
ýýýý««««««««îþîþ
```

I'm wondering how I can determine the size of what was actually read.  In the code below, assume my socket is set up properly.  I've connected to a URL (a plain old web site), sent a request, and have started reading.  When I read the data, I get the data back, plus some extra weirdness.

```
class TcpClient
{
    ...

    boost::asio::streambuf mResponse;
    std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> mSocket;

    ...

    void read()
    {
        boost::asio::async_read( *mSocket, mResponse, 
            boost::asio::transfer_at_least( 1 ), 
            boost::bind( &TcpClient::onRead, shared_from_this(), 
                boost::asio::placeholders::error, 
                boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred ) );
    }

    void onRead( const boost::system::error_code& err, size_t bytesTransferred )
    {
        if ( err ) {
            if ( err == boost::asio::error::eof ) {
                cout << "Read complete" << endl;
            } else {
                cout << "Error" << endl;
            }
        } else {
            char* data = new char[ bytesTransferred ];
            istream stream( &mResponse );
            stream.read( data, bytesTransferred );

            cout  << data << endl;

            delete [] data;
            read();
        }
        mResponse.consume( mResponse.size() );
    }

    ...

};
```

Below is the result of the first packet I receive from http://libcinder.org.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/0.5.33
Date: Fri, 24 May 2013 01:05:55 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Connection: close
Vary: Cookie

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Cinder | The library for professional-quality creative coding in C++</title>

    <meta name="Descýýýý««««««««îþîþ
```

Comment: Try the following: `char* data = new char[ bytesTransferred + 1]; data[bytesTransferred] = 0; //etc...` Does it help?

Comment: Ding, ding, ding!  We have a a winner.  Yeah, I've been looking at this code too long to think to initialize the value of the array.  I was hoping to be able to reconcile any discrepancy between the response buffer's size and bytesTransferred argument, but alas, that is too much to ask...  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Answer came via Igor R.

This...

```
char* data = new char[ bytesTransferred ];
```

...should be...

```
char* data = new char[ bytesTransferred + 1 ];
data[ bytesTransferred ] = 0;
```

Comment: Note that you don't need to read the data from `asio::streambuf` this way. Just access it directly: `const char* data = asio::buffer_cast<const char*>(mResponse.data());`